# date picker dialog show on edit text double click

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

I have a search activity with two edit text fields. I like on edit text click date picker dialog to be show. However when I click on edit text, first the keyboard is shown, then after second click the date picker dialog is shown. Could somebody help me?

Here is activity code

```
package com.example.firstdemoapp.activities;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.example.firstdemoapp.R;
import com.example.firstdemoapp.model.StatusDK;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SearchingTaxActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

private Calendar calendarFrom;
private Calendar calendarTo;
private String myFormat;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
private EditText dateFrom;
private EditText dateTo;

private EditText activeEditText;
private Calendar activeCalendar;

private Spinner spinnerStatusDK;
private ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_tax);

    calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarTo = Calendar.getInstance();
    myFormat="dd/MM/yyyy";
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

    dateFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateFrom);
    dateTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateTo);
    spinnerStatusDK=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatusDK);
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new StatusDK[] {   
                    new StatusDK( 0, "0" ), 
                    new StatusDK( 1, "1" ), 
                    new StatusDK( 2, "2" ), 
                    });

    spinnerStatusDK.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 
    spinnerStatusDK.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    dateFrom.setOnClickListener(this);
    dateTo.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == dateFrom) {
        activeCalendar = calendarFrom;
        activeEditText = dateFrom;
    } else if (v == dateTo) {
        activeCalendar = calendarTo;
        activeEditText = dateTo;
    }
    new DatePickerDialog(SearchingTaxActivity.this, this,
            activeCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            activeCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            activeCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();



}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    activeCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    activeCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
    activeCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

    if (activeEditText != null) {
        activeEditText.setText(sdf.format(activeCalendar.getTime()));
    }

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and the layout for the activity is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/dateFromTextView"
            />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateFrom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_datefrom"
     />

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/dateToTextView"
            />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/dateTo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_dateto"
     />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerStatusDK"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I added android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for edit text in the xml file and this helped me. Because first focus event is fired, and then click event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to hide a keyboard using [InputMethodManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) class

```
private void hideKeyboard(EditText et) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: My problem is I don't like to click twice on edit text to show date picker dialog

Comment: It's possible to call a date picker dialog by the 1st click event on EditText.

Answer (score 0):

This is best solution which is very useful for open any `DatePicker` & `TimePicker` Dialog from `EditText`,

```
editdate.setFocusable(false);
editdate.setKeyListener(null);
```